# Use of ngx-boostrap datepicker in Angular Library

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular-library

I am trying to create an angular library to filter data. A filter type is date hence I have used ngx-bootstrap datepicker in library. Upon building and using in app, I am facing below error message:

[image]

ng-filter.module.ts

```js
declare module BsDatepickerModule {
  interface ModuleWithProviders<T = any> {
    ngModule: Type<T>;
    providers?: Provider[ ];
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [NgFilterComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    BsDatepickerModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  exports: [NgFilterComponent],
  providers: [ ]
})
export class NgFilterModule { }
```

package.json file is as below:

```js
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.14",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

I couldn't find BsDaterangepickerConfig in ngx-bootstrap/datepicker, so don't know from where I can import and how to achieve it.

Please help me in resolving above mentioned issue. Can anyone please help? I am stuck here. If you need more details let me know.

Comment: can you try replacing BsDatepickerModule with BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),

Comment: I had tried and getting below error message while building library itself:
ERROR: Error during template compile of 'NgFilterModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'BsDatepickerModule' was called.

Comment: sry i think i wasnt specific enough. replace it only inside the imports array like this:    imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),...]

Comment: yes, I had tried the same. BsDatepickerModule.forRoot() inside the imports only and that results into above mentioned error. I understand, it works well in angular application but failing in library. Don't know the reason why?